# How would i make my python code below more efficient and simple for this recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion, primes, palindrome

I need to use recursive functions to find all palindromic primes between two integers N, M, supplied as input. (start and endpoints are included).

- A palindrome number is a number that reads the same from the front and the back.
  Examples are: 212, 44, 9009, 4567654.
- To calculate whether a number is a palindrome or not, incorporate your answer to
  question 1.
- A prime number is a number greater than 1 that is only divisible by 1 and itself.

Examples are: 3, 11, 313.

Some examples of palindromic primes are: 11, 191, 313.

You may assume it’s always the case that N>1, and that N≤M.

You MUST NOT use any form of loop in your program!

I have included my code below and was wondering if it could be checked and if it was possible could you explain how I can make it more simple or efficient.(could you include comments to explain the different lines of code as well?)

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit (30000)

def palindromeprimes(M,N,lst):
    def pr_num(point,end = 1):
        if end == point:
            return True
        else:
            if point % end == 0 and end != 1:
                return False
            else:
                return pr_num(point, end + 1)   
            
    def reverse(sub_phrase):
        if sub_phrase == "":
            return sub_phrase
        else:
            return reverse(sub_phrase[1:]) + sub_phrase[0]    
        
    if M >=N:
        if pr_num(M,1):
            if M==int(reverse(str(M))):
                lst.append(M)
        palindromeprimes (M-1,N,lst)
lst = []
N = eval(input("Enter the starting point N: \n"))
M = eval(input("Enter the ending point M: \n"))
print ("The palindromic primes are:")  

palindromeprimes(M,N,lst)

array1 = sorted(lst)
def printlst(array1,pos=0):
    if pos<len(array1):
        print(array1[pos])
        return printlst(array1,pos+1)
printlst(array1,0)
```

sample input/ouput:

```
Enter the starting point N:
200
Enter the ending point M:
800
The palindromic primes are:
313
353
373
383
727
757
787
797
```

Comment: A good measure to analyze your code is to find out the complexity of your time in both running time and memory, maybe you can start from there to see if your algorithm is good enough before a code refactoring to make it look cleaner and simpler. A shorter code is often better ofc, but not always.

Comment: An assignment that says "You MUST NOT use any form of loop in your program" is obviously not concerned about efficiency.

Comment: Also this sort of question is better suited to [code-review].

Comment: any reason, why you are using the eval function while gathering input?

Comment: Don't ever use `eval` on user input, unless you are willing to give any user the opportunity to install malware on your computer!

Answer (score 0):

How about this. This a more shorter. And quicker.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(4000)
def check_prime(num_list,number):
    if num_list==[]:
        print(number)
    else:
        num=num_list[0]
        
        
        if number % num == 0:
            pass
        else:
            num_list.pop(0)
            check_prime(num_list,number)
def check_palindrome(nums):
    nums1=nums[::-1]
    if nums1==nums:
        new_list=list(range(2,int(nums)))
        check_prime(new_list,int(nums))
def check_done(lists):
    if lists!=[]:
        check_palindrome(str(lists[0]))
        lists.pop(0)
        check_done(lists)


start_int=int(input("Enter starting number: "))
ending_int=int(input("Enter ending number: "))
list1=list(range(start_int,ending_int+1))
check_done(list1)
```

Sample testing

```
Enter starting number: 200
Enter ending number: 800
313
353
373
383
727
757
787
797
```

Comment: how would i be able to use this code for larger numbers such as 10000 to 20000

Comment: Yeah, I know, just increase the recursion limit. This is a little slow for large numbers because of no loops

Answer (score 0):

is it really need to be recursive?

if not, this code is more faster and efficient.

```
def isPalindrome(s):
    if (s == s[::-1]) and isPrime(int(s)):
        return True
    return False


def isPrime(number):
    for i in range(2, number):
        if (number % i) == 0:
            return False
    return True


N = eval(input("Enter the starting point N: \n"))
M = eval(input("Enter the ending point M: \n"))
print("The palindromic primes are:")

for N in range(N, M):
    if isPalindrome(str(N)):
        print(N)
```

Comment: "You MUST NOT use any form of loop in your program" was specified by OP

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best solution is one where the parts are understandable and testable independent of the whole.  This solution should be faster on large numbers:

```
def palindromeprimes(start, end):
    def is_prime(number, divisor=3):
        if number < 2:
            return False

        if number % 2 == 0:
            return number == 2

        if divisor * divisor > number:
            return True

        if number % divisor == 0:
            return False

        return is_prime(number, divisor + 2)

    def is_palindrome(string):
        if len(string) <= 1:
            return True

        if string[0] != string[-1]:
            return False

        return is_palindrome(string[1:-1])

    numbers = []

    if start <= end:
        if is_palindrome(str(start)) and is_prime(start):
            numbers.append(start)

        numbers.extend(palindromeprimes(start + 1, end))

    return numbers

print(palindromeprimes(200, 800))
```

Some features include not doing prime testing on even numbers (both speed and fewer recursions); doing the palindrome test ahead of the prime test (do the easier/faster test first); no extra arguments nor precomputing a list; no implicit loops (e.g. `range()` operator).

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
[313, 353, 373, 383, 727, 757, 787, 797]
%
```